# create sql select query filter with two value on same field with and condition

Tags: sql-server

This is  my table :

```
Srlno   Item Code   Category Code   
1       BT/000001     CLR   
2       BT/000001     SIZ   
3       BT/000001     WAT   
1       BT/000002     Swt   
2       BT/000002     Mol   
3       BT/000002     SIZ
```

I use this Query:

```
SELECT Item_Code
FROM T_SubCatogoryDtls   
WHERE SubCat_code in (N'SIZ' , N'Swt')
GROUP BY Item_Code
```

but the result is:

```
BT/000001
BT/000002
```

I need `BT/000002` because category code `Siz` and `Swt` common in this item code 
what is correct query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Item_Code
FROM T_SubCatogoryDtls   
WHERE SubCat_code in (N'SIZ' , N'Swt')
GROUP BY Item_Code
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SubCat_code) = 2
```

`HAVING` filters out any `Item_Code` groups *not* having *both* codes, i.e. `'SIZ'` **and** `'Swt'`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, didn't notice it, so I deleted my answer.